How to integrate BrightcovePlayer into a Jetpack Compose application?
I am developing a fully Jetpack Compose application, and I need to add functionality to play videos using BrightcovePlayer. The issue is that BrightcovePlayer extends Activity, and I can't directly integrate it with Compose.
I have tried using AndroidView to inflate a layout containing the Brightcove view, but I am unsure how to properly implement the BrightcovePlayer functionality. Here is my current code:
AndroidView(
    factory = { context: Context ->
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.brightcove_video, null, false)
        val brightcoveVideoView = view.findViewById<BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView>(R.id.brightcove_video_view)

        // Get the EventEmitter from the SDK and create a catalog request to fetch a video.
        val eventEmitter: EventEmitter = brightcoveVideoView.eventEmitter
        val account = context.getString(R.string.sdk_demo_account)

        val catalog = Catalog.Builder(eventEmitter, account)
            .setBaseURL(Catalog.DEFAULT_EDGE_BASE_URL)
            .setPolicy(context.getString(R.string.sdk_demo_policy))
            .build()

        catalog.findVideoByID(
            context.getString(R.string.sdk_demo_videoId),
            object : VideoListener() {
                override fun onVideo(video: Video) {
                    brightcoveVideoView.add(video)
                    brightcoveVideoView.start()
                }
            })

        view
    },
)

However, my main issue is figuring out how to extend BrightcovePlayer properly and combine it with AndroidView in Compose. What would be the best way to implement this functionality?
Additional notes:

The entire UI is built with Jetpack Compose.
The Brightcove SDK is already configured and works in traditional XML-based views.
I need to play Brightcove videos in a fully Compose-based screen.

